# d3.js stacked bar graph values at end of each bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, sapui5

I am following [Horizontal stack bar](https://bl.ocks.org/caravinden/32a3d192e0e5f6af81f4bcc12adda8f7)

for populating data . how can add the values of each bar graph at the end of each bar . for example

[image]

The above screen shot is for normal horizontal bar chart . but i am expecting for stacked bar graph .Let me know where i can modify code to have this value at the end of each stacked horizontal bar in the code given of above link

Thanks
Prasad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate the total counts for each bar, you will need to do two steps:

1. Transform the data so that you get an array of objects containing both the `date` and the total sum. Referencing to the d3 example you have linked, we will want to sum the integers in the keys of `disease`, `wounds`, and `other`.
2. We pass this transformed data to insert `<text>` elements into your SVG, and position them correctly using the pre-existing scales.

---

### Step 1: Data transformation

You can store our transformed data in a variable called `totals`:

```
var totals = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.date;
  })
  .rollup(function(d) {
    return d3.sum(d, function(g) {
      return g.disease + g.wounds + g.other;
    });
  })
  .entries(data);
```

An explanation of the code above: we basically want to perform a summary based on date, and in this case we can use the `d3.nest()` function. The key will be the date, and we use `d3.nest().rollup()` to perform a sum of the values in `disease`, `wounds`, and `other` keys.

This will create an array of objects in the following format: `totals = [{key: <date>, value: <total>}, {...}]`. Note that the dates are now stored in the `key` and the totals in `value`.

---

### Step 2: Create labels

We bind `totals` to a newly created object, and create new `<text>` elements from it:

```
var totalLabels = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'totals');
totalLabels.selectAll('.total')
  .data(totals)
  .enter().append('text')
  .attr('class', 'total')
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    // Retrieve the correct vertical coordinates based on the date (stored as d.key)
    // Plus some pixel offset so that the text is centered vertically relative to bar
    return yScale(parseDate(d.key)) + yScale.bandwidth() - 2;
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    // Retrieve the horizontal coordinates based on total (stored as d.value)
    // Add 5px offset so the label does not 'stick' to end of stacked bar
    return xScale(d.value) + 5;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    // Inject total as text content (stored as d.value)
    return d.value;
  });
```

An explanation to the code above:

1. We create a `<g>` wrapper to store all your text labels
2. We create text labels by binding `totals` to it using `.data(totals)`. We enter the data, and append `<text>` labels
3. For positioning, we simply reuse the `xScale` and `yScale` that is already defined. You simply pass the totals into `xScale`, i.e. `xScale(d.value)` and the dates into `yScale`, i.e. `yScale(parseDate(d.key))`.
4. Inject text into the element using `d3.text()`, with the totals as the text content, i.e. `d.value`.

---

### Example

With the following code, we can create a modification of the d3.js example you have linked, where you can append totals to the end of the stacked barchart:

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
var initStackedBarChart = {
  draw: function(config) {
    me = this,
      domEle = config.element,
      stackKey = config.key,
      data = config.data,
      margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 50
      },
      parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%Y"),
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      xScale = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]),
      yScale = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([height, 0]).padding(0.1),
      color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20),
      xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale),
      yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%b")),
      svg = d3.select("#" + domEle).append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var stack = d3.stack()
      .keys(stackKey)
      .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);

    var layers = stack(data);
    data.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.total - a.total;
    });
    yScale.domain(data.map(function(d) {
      return parseDate(d.date);
    }));
    xScale.domain([0, d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], function(d) {
      return d[0] + d[1];
    })]).nice();

    var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .data(layers)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "layer")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
      });

    layer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(parseDate(d.data.date));
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[1]) - xScale(d[0])
      });

    var totals = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.date;
      })
      .rollup(function(d) {
        return d3.sum(d, function(g) {
          return g.disease + g.wounds + g.other;
        });
      })
      .entries(data);
      
    var totalLabels = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'totals');
    totalLabels.selectAll('.total')
      .data(totals)
      .enter().append('text')
      .attr('class', 'total')
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        // Retrieve the correct vertical coordinates based on the date (stored as d.key)
        // Plus some pixel offset so that the text is centered vertically relative to bar
        return yScale(parseDate(d.key)) + yScale.bandwidth() - 2;
      })
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        // Retrieve the horizontal coordinates based on total (stored as d.value)
        // Add pixel offset so labels don't stick to end of stacked bars
        return xScale(d.value) + 5;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        // Inject total as text content (stored as d.value)
        return d.value;
      });

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 5) + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .call(yAxis);
  }
}
var data = [{
  "date": "4/1854",
  "total": 8571,
  "disease": 1,
  "wounds": 0,
  "other": 5
}, {
  "date": "5/1854",
  "total": 23333,
  "disease": 12,
  "wounds": 0,
  "other": 9
}, {
  "date": "6/1854",
  "total": 28333,
  "disease": 11,
  "wounds": 0,
  "other": 6
}, {
  "date": "7/1854",
  "total": 28772,
  "disease": 359,
  "wounds": 0,
  "other": 23
}, {
  "date": "8/1854",
  "total": 30246,
  "disease": 828,
  "wounds": 1,
  "other": 30
}, {
  "date": "9/1854",
  "total": 30290,
  "disease": 788,
  "wounds": 81,
  "other": 70
}, {
  "date": "10/1854",
  "total": 30643,
  "disease": 503,
  "wounds": 132,
  "other": 128
}, {
  "date": "11/1854",
  "total": 29736,
  "disease": 844,
  "wounds": 287,
  "other": 106
}, {
  "date": "12/1854",
  "total": 32779,
  "disease": 1725,
  "wounds": 114,
  "other": 131
}, {
  "date": "1/1855",
  "total": 32393,
  "disease": 2761,
  "wounds": 83,
  "other": 324
}, {
  "date": "2/1855",
  "total": 30919,
  "disease": 2120,
  "wounds": 42,
  "other": 361
}, {
  "date": "3/1855",
  "total": 30107,
  "disease": 1205,
  "wounds": 32,
  "other": 172
}, {
  "date": "4/1855",
  "total": 32252,
  "disease": 477,
  "wounds": 48,
  "other": 57
}, {
  "date": "5/1855",
  "total": 35473,
  "disease": 508,
  "wounds": 49,
  "other": 37
}, {
  "date": "6/1855",
  "total": 38863,
  "disease": 802,
  "wounds": 209,
  "other": 31
}, {
  "date": "7/1855",
  "total": 42647,
  "disease": 382,
  "wounds": 134,
  "other": 33
}, {
  "date": "8/1855",
  "total": 44614,
  "disease": 483,
  "wounds": 164,
  "other": 25
}, {
  "date": "9/1855",
  "total": 47751,
  "disease": 189,
  "wounds": 276,
  "other": 20
}, {
  "date": "10/1855",
  "total": 46852,
  "disease": 128,
  "wounds": 53,
  "other": 18
}, {
  "date": "11/1855",
  "total": 37853,
  "disease": 178,
  "wounds": 33,
  "other": 32
}, {
  "date": "12/1855",
  "total": 43217,
  "disease": 91,
  "wounds": 18,
  "other": 28
}, {
  "date": "1/1856",
  "total": 44212,
  "disease": 42,
  "wounds": 2,
  "other": 48
}, {
  "date": "2/1856",
  "total": 43485,
  "disease": 24,
  "wounds": 0,
  "other": 19
}, {
  "date": "3/1856",
  "total": 46140,
  "disease": 15,
  "wounds": 0,
  "other": 35
}];
var key = ["wounds", "other", "disease"];
initStackedBarChart.draw({
  data: data,
  key: key,
  element: 'stacked-bar'
});
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.path-line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: yellow;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

svg {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<h2>Stacked Bar Chart - d3.v4 implementation</h2>
<div id='stacked-bar'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

[Stackchart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768)

See sample - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u16ke14z/)

```js
var data = [
       {
            "interest_rate":"< 4%",
            "Default":60,
            "Charge-off":20,
            "Current":456,
            "30 days":367.22,
            "60 days":222,
            "90 days":198,
            "Default":60
            
         },
         {
            "interest_rate":"4-7.99%",
            "Charge-off":2,
            "Default":30,
            "Current":271,
            "30 days":125,
            "60 days":78,
            "90 days":72
            
           
         }
];

 var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 60
   },
    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 315 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    that = this;


   var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .3);

   var y = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

   var color = d3.scale.category20();

   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");

   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickFormat(d3.format(".0%"));

   var svg = d3.select(".viz-portfolio-delinquent-status").append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function (key) {
    return key !== "interest_rate";
   }));


   data.forEach(function (d) {
    var y0 = 0;

    d.rates = color.domain().map(function (name) {
     console.log();;
     return {
      name: name,
      y0: y0,
      y1: y0 += +d[name],
      amount: d[name]
     };
    });
    d.rates.forEach(function (d) {
     d.y0 /= y0;
     d.y1 /= y0;
    });

    console.log(data);
   });

   data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.rates[0].y1 - a.rates[0].y1;
   });

   x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.interest_rate;
   }));

   svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(xAxis);

   svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis);

   var interest_rate = svg.selectAll(".interest-rate").data(data).enter().append("g").attr("class", "interest-rate").attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.interest_rate) + ",0)";
   });

   interest_rate.selectAll("rect").data(function (d) {
    return d.rates;
   }).enter().append("rect").attr("width", x.rangeBand()).attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.y1);
   }).attr("height", function (d) {
    return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1);
   }).style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.name);
   }).on('mouseover', function (d) {
    var total_amt;
    total_amt = d.amount;



    console.log('----');
    d3.select(".chart-tip").style('opacity', '1').html('Amount: <strong>$' + that.numberWithCommas(total_amt.toFixed(2)) + '</strong>');

   }).on('mouseout', function () {
    d3.select(".chart-tip").style('opacity', '0');
   });

   var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend").data(color.domain().slice().reverse()).enter().append("g").attr("class", "legend").attr("transform", function (d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * -70 + ",283)";
   });


   legend.append("rect").attr("x", width + -53).attr("width", 10).attr("height", 10).style("fill", color);

   legend.append("text").attr("x", width - 40).attr("y", 5).attr("width", 40).attr("dy", ".35em").style("text-anchor", "start").text(function (d) {
    return d;
   });
```

```css
h1 { 
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; 
  text-align:center; 
  margin-top: 80px;
}


.viz-portfolio-delinquent-status {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px
}


 path { fill: #83B0EA;} 
.domain { 
  fill: none; 
  stroke: #000; 
  stroke-width: 1px; 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<h1>D3 Stacked Bar Chart Example</h1>
<div class="viz-portfolio-delinquent-status"></div>
```